# Running Hyprland on Archlinux got black screen

Tags: linux, archlinux

I've followed some tutorial to setup Hyprland. And it seems to be running (If i press multiple time the key to launch a terminal, i can see several launched if i use the top command in TTY2)
My problem seems to be mainly graphics. i don't think it has something to do with Hyprland configuration (a package missing maybe?)

To sum up:

- I have a fresh archlinux on a virtual machine (to setup my config)
- I updated archlinux (pacman -Ssy) I installed my graphics driver
  (AMD), 3D acceleration is enabled,
- After that i installed Hyprland with yay
- and i followed the step here: https://github.com/notwidow/hyprland to
  get some configuration file.

But when i run the command "Hyprland", I remain with a black screen, i think something must be missing in my config because if i install weston and launch it. I have a default gui and i can launch a terminal. And if i launch Hyprland on the weston GUI, it launch itself inside the gui launched by weston. The main difference is that i can see it here.
But i don't know what difference weston launched or not can do? (Moreover i'd like to just have Hyprland and not the GUI of weston)

Does someone know what i could miss?
I tried to set the correct monitor name in hyprland.conf but it didn't change anything

Answer (score 2):

Run wrappedhl.sh with

```
    #!/bin/env sh
    export WLR_NO_HARDWARE_CURSORS=1
    export WLR_RENDERER_ALLOW_SOFTWARE=1
    exec Hyprland
```